# Class Library and Console Application project templates not available on Visual Studio 2015 Express

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

We're growing the team but won't buy more Visual Studio Ultimate licences, so some people will have to work in VS Express edition.

We're testing it, but our projects aren't working on Express. We have projects of type Class Library - compiles into dll - and Console Application. In VS Express, when I try to create new solution/project, all I have is asp.net web application. I believe the installation I did doesn't have support for these templates, and therefore is unable to load those projects.

Is there a way to fix it? Maybe use another Express setup or install those templates separately?

Comment: Is it possible that you've installed the *"Visual Studio 2015 Express for Web"*? There is a separate version for the desktop (*"Visual Studio 2015 Express for Windows Desktop"*)

Comment: Maybe. It wasn't me who installed it. I'm downloading Express for Desktop and will try to install it myself to evaluate it.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Community will be work for you. You can download it from here: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/

Comment: The community edition can only be used by up to 5 developers in *"non-enterprise organizations"*, and it's use is even completely prohibited in *"enterprise organizations*" (>250 PCs or >$1 Million US Dollars in annual revenue). Since the OP is talking of *"growing the team"* I think that the community edition is most likely not a viable solution to use...

Comment: You're right up to their purpose :) It depends their needs

Comment: Yes, we can't use community, I should have expressed that. We need to make VS Express and Ultimate share projects.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Visual Studio 2015 Express for Desktop and those project templates became available.